# Minimum requirements for running ASP.Net Core + Kestrel on .Net 4.6.1

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I have a console application (actually a Service Fabric stateful service), running on Windows x64.
Its `.csproj` currently has a `project.json` file (other dependencies omitted for brevity):

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "net461": {
            "dependencies": {
                "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms": "1.0.1-rc2-24027"
            }
        }
    },
    "runtimes": {
        "win-x64": { }
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble getting Kestrel running - IWebHost.Start throws an exception that `libuv.dll` can't be found (`Unable to load DLL 'libuv': The specified module could not be found`).

What's the proper way of runing ASP.Net core, with Kestrel, on .Net 4.6.1 (.Net core is not an option for me)? It looks like the libuv package only targets win7-*... Why? what should I change?

I'm using VS2015 on Windows 10.

Comment: Which app type do you want to create? https://dotnet.github.io/docs/core-concepts/app-types.html

Comment: It is a console application. And this is *not* a .net core app, so I can't see why this is relevant?

Comment: Does it work if you change your runtimes to `win7-x64`. Windows 7/2008R2 is the lowest supported Windows version. The assumption is that windows versions are backwards compatible so anything win7-XXX will work on newer versions. Sometimes you may want to target a newer version e.g. to use a new API. A bit more on RIDS in my post here: https://blog.3d-logic.com/2015/11/10/using-native-libraries-in-asp-net-5/. win-x64 is kind of an "abstract" version in the RID hierarchy and win7-x64 derives from it (https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/pkg/Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms/runtime.json#L27)

Comment: I can't compile with "win7-x64". Looking at other attempts of this, it looks like I might need to add BaseNuGetRuntimeIdentifier to my csproj... I'll try it out.

Comment: @Pawel - I added BaseNuGetRuntimeIdentifier, changed to win7-x64, and the project compiles. Still, something in the tooling (or my usage) is broken, because when packaging my project, the libuv.dll is not copied.

Comment: Wait a second, why do you have a *.csproj? .NET Core projects have a .xproj + project.json file. There are corner cases where you want to have both, but usually you only the xproj+project.json is sufficient. Second Question would be: DId you even install the rc2-final runtime and preview1 tooling?

Comment: @Tseng - As I wrote before, this is *not* a .Net core project.

Comment: That do not matter, if you want to make an ASP.NET Core Project (targeting .NET 4.5/6 or .NET Core), you have to use .xproj, You should use the designed Project templates for this (there are both, templates for .NET Core and .NET Framework ASP.NET Core applications)